# How to get Command name for current workflow

Tags: workflow

I have created a sample workflow. In this workflow I have multiple states like Draft, Awaiting approval and Done. Each and every state have a command like submit, approve or reject.

I got my current state from workflow using below code

```
 IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(args.DataItem[FieldIDs.Workflow]);
   var currentWorkflowState = workflow.GetState(args.DataItem);
```

Now, I want the current command of the state.

but I got all commands from workflow using below code

```
var currentWorkflowState = workflow.GetCommands(args.DataItem);
```

Kindly assist, Thanks in advance

Comment: by the current command, you mean the first command under the workflow state, correct? try - `var command = workflow.GetCommands(args.DataItem[FieldIDs.WorkflowState]).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your above code might have executed inside an action class. So you may able to get the Command Item from Workflow Pipeline arguments like how you got current state.

to get list of commands in your current state

```
var currentWorkflowState = workflow.GetState(workflowActionArgument.DataItem);
workflow.GetCommands(currentWorkflowState.StateID);
```

to get current command from arguments

```
public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs workflowActionArgument)
{
....
....
    Item commandItem = workflowActionArgument.CommandItem;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Gopinath. Yes, I got it. Get current command name from  var commandItem = workflowActionArgument.CommandItem.Name

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass proper value to `workflow.GetCommands` method.

It should be `WorkflowCommand command = workflow.GetCommands(workflowStateID).ToList();`

`workflowStateID` should be ID of workflow state which you want to get commands for.

See disassembled code from Sitecore.Kernel.dll:

[image]